# C++: Algorithm wrong output ( works on java )

Tags: c++, methods

Can someone help me with my code ? I'm trying to use different algorithm but it returns way to big numbers, when i use algorithm between /*  */ it works perfect, anyone can see whats wrong with my new code ? (same on java works)

```
   int* czynnikiPierwsze(int n)throw (string){
        if(n<0){
            string wyjatek1="Nie mozna rozlozyc ujemnej liczby";
            throw wyjatek1;
            }
        int b=0;
        while(n>2){
            n=n/tab[n-2];
            b++;
        }
    dzielniki=new int[b]();
    int j=0;
        while(n>2){
            dzielniki[j]=tab[n-2];
            n=n/tab[n-2];
            j++;
        }
      /*  int a=n;
        int*dzielniki=new int[30]();
        for(int j=0;j<n+a;j++){
            while(n>2){
            dzielniki[j]=tab[n-2];
            n=n/tab[n-2];
            break;
            }
        }*/
        return dzielniki;
        }
```

Comment: There is no way we can give you an answer without even knowing what the algorithm should do.

Answer (score 1):

There's no chance your second `while(n>2)` loop runs even once, since the first loop only exited when that same condition was no longer true.

Comment: Thats not it, after adding a=n and using a in second loop it still doesn't work.